# Migrate local database to Firebase database BLOB type is not converting

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, blob

I have images and I am storing it in database as a BLOB file type. Now I want to migrate Firebase online database. because of Firebase database can not support Blob type, I've stored BLOB file as a String type such as "137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68..." (just put in " ", normaly numbers are a BLOB file). Now how can convert it to BLOB file and a make it Bitmap again.

in short:

my String like this "137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68..."

```
    String value = new String(byteArray);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68...};
```

and I want to convert it byte array like above

Comment: It might be more effectient to store the images inside [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), and then save the url link to the images inside your database

Comment: You are right but this database is very old I didnt find the original images. only BLOB type images exist

Comment: It's fairly straight forward to read the BLOB's and then save them as... jpg's (for example).

Comment: OKEY I am trying to use Firebase Storage, can you help my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762263/using-firebase-storage-image-with-glide