# Android Glide does not load images from url with `;`

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading

I'm using Glide to load images in my app and I encountered some problem with loading images from a url that contains a **;**. The image path is something like

```
https://adbutler-fermion.com/getad.img/;libID=502532
```

It throws a **Glide exception failed to load resource**. All other images are loading fine except for one with the special character **;** within the Url. My stack trace is as below

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Bad Gateway
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:118)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:53)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:275)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:245)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:220)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:347)
```

I tried with

```
Glide.with(context).load(imageUri).into(postImage);
```

using both string url and a uri. How can I fix this.

Comment: Can you show Image path?

Comment: Can you remove `;` from your url?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Actually the image path is a generated one. So I don't have control over it from the mobile App

Comment: ok. Can you post the url your are facing problem with?

Comment: I posted the image Url in the content

Comment: I tested the url using Glide 4.7.1 and it worked.

Comment: I was using Glide 4.0.0-RC0. Updated to 4.6.1 and working fine. Hats off @Geros. Thank you !

Comment: but before passing image url to `Glide` you can definitely remove the `;` from String

Comment: is that possible accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762263/using-firebase-storage-image-with-glide