# Retrieve Image from Firebase using Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, picasso, android-glide

I am trying to display my image that stores successfully in Firebase. But whenever I try and display the image it returns a blank image and not the image stored. I think that the image name is wrong when being stored in Firebase. I also did research to try use Glide in my code but don't know how to implement it. I am using the latest dependencies for Firebase.

#### Code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

        InitializeFields();

        userName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UpdateSettings();
            }
        });

        RetrieveUserInfo();

        userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);
            }
        });
    }

    private void UpdateSettings() {
        String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String setUserStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your user name first....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserStatus)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your status....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
            profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
            profileMap.put("status", setUserStatus);
            profileMap.put("image", photoUrl);

            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                SendUserToMainActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void RetrieveUserInfo() {
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")))) {
                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                            photoUrl = retrieveProfileImage;


                            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            userStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);

                            //Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                            Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(userProfileImage);

                            //Glide.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);

                        }
                        else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))) {
                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            userStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);
                        }
                        else {
                            userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please set & update your profile information...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void InitializeFields() {
        UpdateAccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        userProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(SettingsActivity.this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your profile image is updating...");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            final String downloadedUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                                    .setValue(downloadedUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image saved in Database Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                //Glide.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(downloadedUrl).into(userProfileImage);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Realtime Database before

[Realtime Database before - Watch User Warren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q196t.png)

#### Realtime Database after

[Realtime Database after - Watch User Warren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7uB.png)

#### Storage before

[Storage before adding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4xmp.png)

#### Storage after

[Storage after image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldcdD.png)

Comment: For Glide, did you add a Glide module class? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762436/8051742
More information : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage

Comment: can you please add screenshot of your firebase realtime database, 
before update profile, and after update profile . both db pic

Comment: @MUFAzmi I have added the images for the Realtime Database and Storage before and after as requested.

Comment: @PabiMoloi where would I add Glide to my code? As I don't know where to implement it in my code