# cannot load image from Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

cannot load image from Glide

it will get error. `com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/camping-ee9d0.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1633920523821.null?alt=media&token=9056823d-e2df-40f8-858e-1415903942af]`

but the URL is correct.

this is the code.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CamperSiteModel camperSiteModel = mPost.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(camperSiteModel.getCamperSiteImages()).into(holder.post_image);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your ModelLoader class?

Comment: @AmadYus I not use that, so I dont' know why I get that error

Comment: @AmadYus I solve this problem, I modify this one `Glide.with(context).load(camperSiteModel.getCamperSiteImages().get(position)).into(holder.post_image)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Firebase Storage image with Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762263/using-firebase-storage-image-with-glide)